# DynamoDB update with ADD action on a numeric attribuite

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

So I have this table where rows have one of the two set of attributes. A row starts it's life with one set, then goes into second set (and stays that way until removed). Both sets have one attribute in common.

The problem is that I'd like to transform row from first attribute set into second attribute set with just update. I do not want to do a read, just to get that single, common attribute. I figured out, that if you do an UpdateRequest, every attribute not contained in the update is wiped out. Since the common attribute is a numerical i figured out I'll cheat a bit with ADD attribute action like this:

```
new AttributeValueUpdate()
  .withAction(AttributeAction.ADD)
  .withValue(new AttributeValue().withN("0"));
```

According to [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html), this action in conjuction with attribute type (Number) is supposed to add value (0 in this case) to current attribute value. However, this behaves like PUT action as after the operation this attribute has 0 as its value.

So the questions are:

1. Is ADD action working like I'm expecting it to? In other words, does adding 0 to attribute makes it survive UpdateRequest? If so, what can I be doing wrong as it doesn't seem to be working for me?
2. Assuming ADD action is working as intended and I just have misinterpreted it's role -- is there any other way to preserve attribute value during update?

Comment: The updateItem API should allow you to partially update like as you desire.  However, it will insert an item if the primary key doesn't exist.  As for if the attribute doesn't exist, in the documentation in mentions that it takes a default value of 0 if it doesn't exist.  So I would either double check if you attribute is just 0 or it doesn't exist.

Comment: @RaymondLin After double checking with a temporary `GetItem` request before update, it turned out that the attribute in question wasn't there. If you would like to create an answer, I'll be happy to vote it up and accept it.

Comment: Sure, I'll go ahead and do that.  Glad you got it to work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The updateItem API allows you to partially update your item. However, it will insert an item if the primary key doesn't exist.  If the attribute doesn't exist though, it takes a default value of 0 if it doesn't exist. So I would either double check if your attribute is set to 0 or it doesn't exist to confirm your result.